# affect only the clicked element in jquery for multiple elements with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, click

i've been looking all over for a solution to this but i just can't figure out how.

what i want is for the specific header that was clicked to be the only one to expand.

demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/bm92L0eg/1/

html:

```
<h3 class="click-list">header a</h3>
<ul class="open-list">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>

<h3 class="click-list">header b</h3>
<ul class="open-list">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>

<h3 class="click-list">header c</h3>
<ul class="open-list">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
$('.click-list').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.open-list').slideToggle(600);
});
```

that jquery code didn't work while this code below is the one that acivates all headers:

```
$('.open-list').slideToggle(600);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.next()` to select the adjacent `.open-list` element.

It should be:

```
$('.click-list').click(function () {
    $(this).next('.open-list').slideToggle(600);
});
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2yzyjwo4/)

Comment: i see. i'm still somewhat new to jquery so it's quite hard for me to figure out how next & other stuff like bind works. thanks! =)